# Integral commutative algebra's definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, definition, integral-domain, algebras

I was reading a text where I found the expression

> Take an integral commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

It' doesn't give a definition so I don't know what it means for $\textbf{integral}$. Now I don't know if it means that the algebra is an integral domain as a ring or if  it is integrally closed. Hence I want to ask if there is a standard definition of integral commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

thanks in advance.

Comment: dear LuckyS, would you mind giving the name of the text? was there any context around that sentence that might give some insight?

Comment: The text is not findable online but the first aim is define a commutative algebra X over this integral commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra S, equipped with a derivation and a residue map. Now, I would think that it means "integral domain".

Comment: Integral as an adjective usually denotes the object being an integral domain. If it were integrally closed, I suspect that the author would have used the term ‘normal’.

Comment: Thank you Daniel